# What does Type "ref|filter" mean in mariaDB Explain Output

Tags: mariadb, sql-execution-plan, explain

Trying to troubleshoot a MariaDB query.  We did an `explain select` on the select.  A couple of the rows in the output have value `ref|filter` for the `type` column.

What does this mean?  The [MariaDB docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/) mention `ref` but make no mention of `filter` or `ref|filter` as a possible value for this column.

Using MariaDB 10.5

Comment: Can I get one thing really clear - dev.mysql.com is NOT the MariaDB docs. https://mariadb.com/kb/ is.

Comment: Oops.  Quite right.  hade checked both and used the wrong link

Comment: Updated link to be correct now

Comment: Updated link contents :-)

Comment: Please add the query so others can lean something from this.  Also `CREATE TABLE` and the full `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: @RickJames: The full query I was looking at is quite complex and includes several tables.  I don't believe adding it is minimal example or adds anything to this question which was about what the explain output means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [rowid filtering](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rowid-filtering-optimization/) where the filter refers the usage of the second index.